# Set the default link description

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I am tryping out [org-wiki.el](https://github.com/caiorss/org-wiki) to create a personal wiki in org-mode. The package offers a custom link type `wiki:<page>` which creates a link like `wiki:myPage` that matches up with `myPage.org`.

I'm wondering if there is any way to set the default description for this link type to hide the `wiki:` prefix, so that on completing the link, it converts to `[[wiki:myPage][myPage]]`?

Or better yet, typing `[[wiki:My page]]` which automatically displays as `[[wiki:My page][My page]]` so we can ditch the camelCase!

Any ideas?

thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The function `org-wiki-insert` inserts a `wiki:` link of the form `[[wiki:MyHeading][MyHeading]]`.

But, it's more convenient to use the built-in `org-insert-link`.  For that we need two things: completions for the link target and a default description.  For the first, we just need to define a function called `org-wiki-complete-link` and `org-mode` will pick it up for completing `wiki:` links:

```
(defun org-wiki-complete-link (&optional arg)
  (org-wiki--helm-selection
   (lambda (page)
     (format "wiki:%s" page))))
```

The only way to set default descriptions seems to be to set `org-make-link-description-function`.  There isn't a per-type function like there is with the targets.  We just have to make sure that we only complete `wiki:` type links:

```
(defun org-make-wiki-link-description (link desc)
  (when (string-prefix-p "wiki:" link)
    (string-remove-prefix "wiki:" link)
    )
  )
(setq org-make-link-description-function #'org-make-wiki-link-description)
```

Now, hit `C-c C-l` and type `wiki:[return]`.  You will be prompted for the wiki heading and then a default description will be added.

Comment: Wow, thanks @erikstokes ! I added your functions to my init.el file. I then reloaded Emacs. I hit `C-c C-l` and type `wiki:` and `[return]`. Then Helm presents me with a list of existing wiki pages and prompts me for a `pattern:`. So I type `Test wiki article`. But when I hit `[return]` I receive an error: "Wrong type argument: stringp, nil". Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me so I'm not sure.  `org-make-wiki-link-description` does return `nil` sometimes so it's probably from that somehow.  Can you get a trackback on the error and post it somewhere?

Comment: Okay, it looks like this works for pages that already exist. But if you type the name of a page you want to create, it triggers an error...

Comment: It would be nice if the default description was autofilled in the minibuffer as `Description: This is the default description` so that you can change this if you want...